# Redirection using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application in which I'd like to perform a redirection using Javascript:

```
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location);
console.log(sPageURL);
var lengthUrl = sPageURL.split('/').length;
var NewUrl = '';
sPageURL.split('/').forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (index < lengthUrl - 2) NewUrl += item;
  if (index == lengthUrl - 1) {
    if (item == "Organisateur") NewUrl += sPageURL.split('/')[lengthUrl - 2];
  }
});
console.log(NewUrl);
window.location = NewUrl;
```

I get as output:

> http://localhost:31569/Event/2
>
> http://localhost:31569/Event/localhost:31569

The problem is that the new URL is concatenated with the old one: I'd like `http://localhost:31569/Event/2` be replaced by `localhost:31569`.

I tried `window.location =` , `window.location.href =` and `window.location.replace` and I get the same result .

So I need to know:

1. What is the reason of this problem ?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just do `window.location = "/"` if you want to navigate to the root of the URL?

Comment: @KianCross good it works : a simple and good solution. But I still not understand what is the problem with my code ( plz post your comment as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `window.location = "/"` should navigate to the host name of the web page, which I think is what you're trying to do.

The problem you are having sounds like you have not included the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) in front of the URL you want to navigate to.